# How to catch exceptions from gsoap?

Tags: iphone, soap, exception, gsoap

I'm currently building an iphone app based on gsoap for the communication. I'm trying to manage connection problems and I can't find any specific return statement when the device is not connected to host.

Is there a way to get some kind of exceptions when running gsoap send or reicv methods?

Thanks for help,

Romain

Comment: The solution is finally dumb. The generated requests return a statement SOAP_OK in case of success. In iphone case, the test is made like this :
soap_call___method(&soap,NULL,NULL, &request,&response) == SOAP_OK

Comment: To check whether device is connected to host or not, you can  use [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/index.html) code.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html there is even a useful function for printing a human readable error message:

```
#include "soapcalcProxy.h"  // get proxy 
#include "calc.nsmap"    // get namespace bindings 
int main() 
{ 
   calc s; 
   double r; 
   if (s.ns2__add(1.0, 2.0, r) == SOAP_OK) 
      std::cout << r << std::endl; 
   else
      soap_print_fault(s.soap, stderr); 
   return 0; 
}
```